# ArangoDB Get Tree Root Nodes

Tags: arangodb, arangodb-graph

I’m storing basic hierarchical game trees in ArangoDB as graphs. Each game tree has a start node, and each node (including the start node) 2-5 edges (actions). I have 2 collections, nodes for vertices and actions for edges.

I’m using the Node JS SDK and I’m trying to find the best way to query all start nodes? Should I add an isRoot property to nodes and query the nodes collection using that? Or should I query all nodes doing a filter using the actions collection to find nodes without inbound edges? Or a separate collection of start nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traversal or aggregation-based approaches to find root nodes will not be very efficient. The fastest option is probably to add an `isRoot` attribute that you can query for and potentially index.

You could also create an extra vertex that has an outgoing edge to every root node so that you can do a 1-hop traversal from this node to all root nodes. But that could get in the way if you want to traverse in the opposite direction and that node would be a supernode that one typically tries to avoid.